# Change textarea text color that written after maxLength in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to do something like this in a `textArea` tag when it hits the maxLength?

here's what i did so far:

```
onKeyUp={(val) => {
  const len = answer.length;
  if (len >= 500) {
     textAreaRef.current.textContent = textAreaRef.current.textContent.substring(0, 500);
     textAreaRef.current.css = 'border: 1px solid red'
  } 
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. What's your problem?

Comment: I wanna mark the text that exceeded the maxlength to red in a textarea using ReactJS

Comment: What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can’t do styles to specific characters inside the textarea using ReactJS.

Comment: Considering you're using twitter as inspiration, look at what they've done? They're not using a textarea

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wanna use it inside a textArea not anything else

Comment: There's a reason twitter don't use a textarea. It's likely that using a textarea is highly limiting.